# Print Fit To Width with XML Spreadsheet in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, spreadsheet

I have an XML Spreadsheet that is automatically generated. There is a varying amount of Columns and Rows depending on the report.

When printing I would like for it to Fit to Width (Right now if there are too many columns it will not fit on a page... even when landscape).

I was initially using FitToPage but for reports with hundreds of rows it needs to go onto multiple pages.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out...

You have to use **FitToPage**

And **FitHeight** (which sets the number of pages to print to) to get it to fit to width and have multiple pages...

Here is an example of it working.

```
<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
       <PageSetup>
        <Layout x:Orientation="Landscape"/>
        <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
        <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
        <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
       </PageSetup>
       <FitToPage/>
       <Print>
        <FitHeight>100</FitHeight>
        <ValidPrinterInfo/>
        <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
        <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution>
       </Print>
       <Selected/>
       <Panes>
        <Pane>
         <Number>3</Number>
         <ActiveRow>6</ActiveRow>
         <ActiveCol>8</ActiveCol>
        </Pane>
       </Panes>
       <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
       <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
      </WorksheetOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA I'd use

```
.FitToPagesWide = 1
```

off of the PageSetup property of the sheet.

Comment: [Don't forget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509583/excel-2007-pagesetup-fittopageswide-problem/2509715#2509715) to set `Zoom` to `False`!