# Excel 2007 PageSetup.FitToPagesWide issue

Tags: c#, excel

For while I have been trying to set the Page Scaling of Excel page in a Microsoft Visual Studio project for Excel 2007 using C#

The code looks like this

```
private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;  
    PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1;
    PageSetup.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
    PageSetup.PaperSize = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
}
```

The lines for PaperSise and Orientation are working well, however I can't make Excel fit data onto one page.

Am I doing something wrong ?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms272408%28v=Office.11%29.aspx) did not help much because they do not yet have a code sample for this language.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I should have clearly read the Remarks section on the page I mentioned. It states:

> **"If the Zoom  property is True, the FitToPagesTall property is ignored."**

And my code now looks like this, works like charm

```
private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PageSetup.Zoom = false;
    PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
    PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1;
    PageSetup.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
    PageSetup.PaperSize = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;         
}
```

Comment: This works great.  However, if you need to set PageSetup.FitToPagesWide and you do not want to set PageSetup.FitToPagesTall you will need to set this value to false instead of an integer.

Comment: Wonderful.  Exactly what i was looking for.