# Print Preview and setting properties with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet that I have a print preview module where several properties are set.  When I go to the actual print preview, I always have to set the orientation, scaling and fit document on one page.  The issue is that I have a module set up to take care of that but is isn;t working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code module:

```
Sub PrintFrm()

Dim lr As Long
Dim lc As Long

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .LeftHeader = "Page &P of &N"
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = "Cycle Count"
         .CenterFooter = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy" & " at " & "hh:mm:ss")
        .RightFooter = "Printed by: " & Application.UserName
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
    End With
    Range("C3:C" & lr).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.PrintCommunication = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The macro recorder is misleading on this one because it doesn't include it, but for `.FitToPagesWide = 1` and `.FitToPagesTall = False` to take effect, you'll need to set `.Zoom` to `False`.

```vb
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
            '...
    End With
```

This basically has the same effect as when you change the value of the radio button in the Page Setup Settings.

[image]

Related article:

- https://blog.softartisans.com/2011/06/04/kb-fittopagestall-and-fittopageswide-settings-do-not-take-effect/

Related question:

- [Excel 2007 PageSetup.FitToPagesWide issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509583/excel-2007-pagesetup-fittopageswide-issue)

Note that I was not able to reproduce your issue with `.Orientation`.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that and let you know.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: @TeachASU - Any success or issues?